# I've to create a deepArray2String method that expects a 2D int array 'x' and returns its string representation

Tags: java, arrays

Create a deepArray2String method that expects a 2D int array 'a1' and returns its string representation, which can be written to the console.

I've tried some logics but i'm getting this error:

**tester**.java:18: error: incompatible types: StringBuffer cannot be converted to String
   return result;
           ^

```
public String deepArray2String(int[][] a1){

    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < a1[i].length; j++) {
            result.append("[" + a1[i][j] + "]");
            if (j == a1.length && i != a1.length-1) {
                result.append(",");
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

System.out.println (deepArray2String (new int [] [] {{1}, {2}, {4}}));

Output should be [1], [2], [4]]

System.out.println (deepArray2String (new int [] [] {{1}, {2, 3}}));

Output should be [[1], [2, 3]]

System.out.println (deepArray2String (new int [] [] {}));

Output should be []

System.out.println (deepArray2String (new int [] [] {{5, 3}, {1}, {-1, 1}}));

Output should be [[5, 3], [1], [-1, 1]]

Comment: StringBuffer is obsolete for years. Use StringBuilder.

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to reinvent the wheel, Java already has a built static method in  [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[])) that does this. [Autoboxing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/autoboxing.html) means it will work with arrays of any primitive type.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import org.junit.Test;
import lombok.extern.slf4j.Slf4j;

@Slf4j
public class ExampleTest {

    @Test
    public void test() {
        log.info(Arrays.deepToString(new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 4 } }));    
        log.info(Arrays.deepToString(new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2, 3 } }));    
        log.info(Arrays.deepToString(new int[][] {}));
        log.info(Arrays.deepToString(new int[][] { { 5, 3 }, { 1 }, { -1, 1 } }));
    }
}
```

**Results**

```
[main] INFO coaching.arrays.ExampleTest - [[1], [2], [4]]
[main] INFO coaching.arrays.ExampleTest - [[1], [2, 3]]
[main] INFO coaching.arrays.ExampleTest - []
[main] INFO coaching.arrays.ExampleTest - [[5, 3], [1], [-1, 1]]
```

**Parameters works exactly the same way**.

```
@Test
public void test() {
    int[][] a = new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2 }, { 4 } };
    log.info(Arrays.deepToString(a));

    int[][] a2 = new int[][] { { 1 }, { 2, 3 } };
    log.info(Arrays.deepToString(a2));

    int[][] a3 = new int[][] {};
    log.info(Arrays.deepToString(a3));

    int[][] a4 = new int[][] { { 5, 3 }, { 1 }, { -1, 1 } };
    log.info(Arrays.deepToString(a4));
}
```

Comment: I have to pass values through parameters. These are just for examples

Answer (score 0):

Your method's signature says that it returns a String, but you're trying to return a StringBuffer.  Make that last line:

```
return result.toString();
```

Comment: Now it's working but I'm getting different output. Is my code correct?

Answer (score 0):

You have got wrong the places where you should put square brackets. To find out where you should put them, try to think of how many nested brackets you can have? Since the array is 2-dimensional, the answer is 2, so it is enough to surround the loops with the brackets.

Modify the code like this:

```
public static String deepArray2String(int[][] a1){
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    result.append("[");
    for (int i = 0; i < a1.length; i++) {
        result.append("[");
        for (int j = 0; j < a1[i].length; j++) {
            result.append(a1[i][j]);
            if (j != a1[i].length - 1 ) {
                result.append(",");
            }
        }
        result.append("]");
        if(i != a1.length - 1) {
            result.append(",");
        }
    }
    result.append("]");
    return result.toString();
}
```